# Inferring types from a variable in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript3.0

Assume I have a dictionary which maps component names to the actual components as follows:-

```
const FC1 = ({prop} : {prop: number}) => <>{prop}</>;
const FC2 = ({prop} : {prop: string}) => <>{prop}</>;
const mapComponents =  [
  {type : "Functional Component 1", element : FC1},
  {type : "Functional Component 2", element : FC2}
]
```

And I have a helper function to construct the required elements as follows:-

```
const ConstructComponent = ({type, props}: {type : string, props? : any}) => {
  for(const x of mapComponents){
    if(x.type === type){
      return <x.element {...props}/>
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

This way, I can easily call any component in the map using a jsx expression as

```
<ConstructElement type="Functional Component 1" props={{prop1 : 123}}/>
```

I want to make this as type-safe as possible. I know this is possible by manually creating a type like :-

```
type ConstructComponentProps = ({type : "Functional Component 1", props : React.ComponentProps<typeof FC1>}) | ({type : "Functional Component 2", props : React.ComponentProps<typeof FC2>})
```

So here are my questions:-

1) Is there an easier way to achieve this? I was thinking in the lines of being able to automatically infer the type from the mapComponents constant. I know this doesn't work, but something like:-

```
type ConstructComponentProps = mapComponents.map((obj) => {type : obj.type, props: React.ComponentProps<typeof obj.element>})
```

2) Can I get all the possible values of the 'type' property in this format? Something that gives me a type like :-

```
type types = "Functional Component 1" | "Functional Component 2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) types of the `type` properties of the elements of `mapComponents`, you'll need to tell the compiler not to widen them to `string` which is the default behavior.  Since TS3.4 you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask for the narrowest possible inferred type:

```
const mapComponents = [
  { type: "Functional Component 1", element: FC1 },
  { type: "Functional Component 2", element: FC2 }
] as const
```

Once you do this, you can then build up the types you want from it.  Here's how I'd determine `ConstructComponentProps`:

```
type _ConstructComponentProps<C extends typeof mapComponents[number] =
  typeof mapComponents[number]> = C extends any ?
  { type: C["type"], props: React.ComponentProps<C["element"]> } : never;

type ConstructComponentProps = _ConstructComponentProps
/* type ConstructComponentProps = {
    type: "Functional Component 1";
    props: {
        prop: number;
    };
} | {
    type: "Functional Component 2";
    props: {
        prop: string;
    };
} */
```

This works by using a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) (which is the `C extends any ? ...` syntax, where `C` is a generic type parameter) to pull apart the union of elements of `mapComponents` into individual pieces and act on each of them.  There are other ways to do this but they will all involve conditional types in some form.

And then your `Types` is a simple [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types):

```
type Types = ConstructComponentProps["type"];
// type Types = "Functional Component 1" | "Functional Component 2"
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4AxAYQEY4BeOACgG84wOMHAC+ALjj9BEMBJoBXEACMkUUQEpOAPjgAeLb2lgRugPRaK1ek2YAmTjylDREpzIkMowGgHMN2vQMjE3NLWgY4EBQwZlxIGiQaGDoHAG1yOEk4GABPMCQJfEZ5GgxgWhQAGzhY8FpE+FZ8ABo4JEqkEAaJFnYRZoys3PzC4tKYcpoqmrj6pLhbFraOrqSeu1FyAF04FBSrBkoD+FjrKHkMWviGhz5svKRWoxTxIYePGC9fJ6E6AH4JCgaDl-BwdLxBphoDxjnAAB5wCCYSLRK5zZKafiDTLAZHcOEAOmGSE4HC4xMx2MycCIMHkUBoekJ7U6N14BI5zxEcHMVJEg35mVp9MZCkqlXI-PIulOnguMDRCXmxI4RRKZQq1UVNyaAl+HF4bjArAkrFsAGZRNzeeRiXAAPqyz7y7VJAAKvxlbThMESABMUsSkSiYrMlclUgplKodhxBkHkVFQ3Vw3RI4oVFAtjouMxvb6aAHdsC4H9BvxiRJmKl8MT8FsfjI6BJkOgYATXTAPU2ZTWWasYPWdNy5EgAG6qCh2p3nS5hhrdsApLiO8LOucphe-cimABU93yMzOLvn7t+Dgh1IPBQIYw1Uy1p8aZCpz1cVKvRjkGcnfIo3IAH0kKlK1vdUJk1GZN3mRYKE-X53yveD3DgTxvB8ODqREf84F3UxKDtAAVB5lyPOUN2uM8mxrOstgoUxTGvOBiPyUi1XGSZpk7OBdSA9j7y4p8FnwSggA)

Comment: This helped me a lot!. Can you please also elaborate on the <C extends typeof mapComponents[number] = typeof mapComponents[number]> part of the syntax? Or if you have any useful links/videos that can help me understand would be helpful too.

Comment: `typeof mapComponents[number]` is the union of the type of elements of the `mapComponents` array (that is, `(typeof mapComponents)` is an array type, and looking up its `[number]` property means getting the type of its elements).  `C extends ...` means we're [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `C` to that type, and `= ...` means we're setting a [default](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) type for `C`.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
const FC1 = ({prop} : {prop: number}) => <>{prop}</>;
const FC2 = ({prop} : {prop: string}) => <>{prop}</>;
const mapComponents = {
  "Functional Component 1": FC1,
  "Functional Component 2": FC2
};

type MapComponents = typeof mapComponents;
type PropsOf<T> = T extends React.ComponentType<infer P> ? P : never;

function ConstructComponent <T extends keyof MapComponents, P extends PropsOf<MapComponents[T]>>({type, props}: {type: T, props?: P}) {
  for(const x in mapComponents){
    if(x === type){
      const Component = mapComponents[x];
      return <Component {...props} />;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

This `<ConstructComponent type="Functional Component 2" props={{prop: 123}} />` would throw this error: `The expected type comes from property 'prop' which is declared here on type '{ prop: string; }'`, because the type `Functional Component 2` expects a prop called `prop` of type string.

2) by changing `mapComponents` to an object, you can get its keys